# Function to check if a variable name is valid

Tags: validation, variables, coldfusion

I have some code using the `SetVariable` function which takes the first parameter as a variable name created based on a variable name passed to this code.

I'm looking for a way to check the string passed to it is a valid variable name using a function rather than using a try/catch block to trap this error.

I know there's a function `IsValid` but this only checks if the variable is valid, not if it's a valid variable name. Does anyone have any suggestions or custom code they've used to do this?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Don't know enough of coldfusion but I know it supports regexp. You could test the variable name against one like [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]* (has to start with alpha and may contain any alpha, number or underscore after that) --> Adjust regexp to whatever is appropiate for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I know there's a function IsValid but this only checks if the variable
>   is valid, not if it's a valid variable name

Actually IsValid() **will** do what you want if you specify "variableName" as the type.

```
<cfoutput>#IsValid( "variableName","1")#</cfoutput>
```

Will output NO, since variable names in CF cannot begin with a digit.